# how to use mysql case or sub query in single query

Tags: mysql

I have tried like this code:

```
SELECT
  ca.batch_code, s.stu_surname, s.cdc_no, s.passport_no,
  p.special_approval, p.special_approval_amount  
FROM  course_apply ca 
  INNER JOIN student s ON ca.stu_code = s.stu_code
  INNER JOIN payment_detail p ON p.stu_code = ca.stu_code
ORDER BY ca.batch_code ASC
```

I need output like that:

Special approval available means display special approval amount otherwise that field value 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ca.batch_code, s.stu_surname, s.cdc_no, s.passport_no,
  p.special_approval, 
  case
    when p.special_approval  = 'available' then p.special_approval_amount 
    else 0
    end as approval_amount
FROM  course_apply ca 
  INNER JOIN student s ON ca.stu_code = s.stu_code
  INNER JOIN payment_detail p ON p.stu_code = ca.stu_code
ORDER BY ca.batch_code ASC
```

Comment: how to check muliple condition in case query

Comment: select ca.batch_code,ca.batch_start_date,ca.batch_end_date,cc.course_abbreviation,ca.stu_code,
CASE
cc.nod = count(a.student_code) THEN cc.nod
ELSE 1
END as attendance
from course_apply ca
INNER JOIN create_course cc on cc.course_code = ca.course_code
inner join attendance a on a.student_code = ca.stu_code
where ca.stu_code='LATS-STU-1003'
if attendance percentage and course number of days equal means
attendance value 1 or 0
any body reply me soon

Comment: This looks like a different question and you should raise it as new question.